# Cannot get test result if running over 1000 Test cases in selenium python

Tags: python, eclipse, selenium, automated-tests

I'm using eclipse program to run selenium python, but there is an issue that when I run over 1000 TCs in one times, only 1000 first TC have test result. If I separate these TCs to many parts with each part is less than 1000 TC, the test result is received completely. I think the issue is not from coding, how can I fix this ? :(

Comment: can you show the code?

Answer (score 0):

which unit test framework you are using, and why you are running from eclipse, i mean it's good for testing but eventually you will have to integrate that with Jenkins or other software so can you try running from command line and see what's happening.

by the way, what error you are getting?